# Average of an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, floating-point

How would I find the average of the indexes in an ArrayList while using the data type float, I need the method to be called:

```
public static ArrayList<Float> PrefixAverage(ArrayList<Float> X){

}
```

I do not need to make an array as the array is preset however i do not have access to the data within the arraylist, all i need is the method to find the average float.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ExampleList {
    public static void main(Float[] args) {
        public static ArrayList<Float> PrefixAverage(ArrayList<Float> X){           
            total += li.get(i);
            avg = total / li.size();
            System.out.println("The Average is: " + avg);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are missing loop. Your method should actually `return` the value.

Comment: Also decide on the name of your list variable: `X` vs `li`.

Comment: typing "PrefixAverage" into google gives me reasonable implementations, which part are you struggling with?

Comment: Also, be aware that your main method is not a real main method because the parameter must be an array of strings, not floats. You will be able to call that method statically from the code but not starting the java program with the JVM

Answer (score 0):

A `prefix average` computes the running average of values in a list or an array. For `10, 20, 30` the running average would be `10, 15, 20`.  So each average is the sum of `i values` divided by `i` where `i` iterates from `1` to the `size` of the list.

```
List<Float> values = new ArrayList<>(
        List.of(1.0f, 2.0f, 4.4f, 10.2f, 9.8f, 12.6f, 22f));
List<Float> results = prefixAverage(values);

System.out.println(results);
```

prints

```
[1.0, 1.5, 2.4666667, 4.4, 5.4800005, 6.6666665, 8.857142]
```

- stream the indices from `1` to `list.size()`
- map to a `sublist` of the list going from `0` to current index (exclusive).
- stream that `sublist` and do a reduction to compute the average.
- return those averages in a list.

```
public static List<Float> prefixAverage(List<Float> values) {
     return IntStream.rangeClosed(1, values.size())
             .mapToObj(i -> values.subList(0, i).stream().reduce(0f,
                     (sum, value) -> sum + value) / i)
             .toList();
}
```